# build.gradle file does not find a property from the gradle.properties file

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle.properties

In my `build.gradle` file, I have a reference to a property that is in the `gradle.properties` file:

```
    credentials {
        username "$USERNAME"
        password "$PASSWORD"
    }
```

And in the gradle.properties file:

```
USERNAME=BLAH
PASSWORD=BLAHBLAH
```

In Intellij, I have an error:

> A problem occurred evaluating root project 'my-Project'.
> Could not get unknown property 'USERNAME' for Credentials [username: null] of type org.gradle.internal.credentials.DefaultPasswordCredentials_Decorated.

I doubled check the name of the property + restarted the computer + invalidated the cache in the Intellj, but nothing seems to help

Answer (score 0):

So after looking in the `Intellij`'s

> File -> Setttings -> Build Execution -> Build Tools -> Gradle -> "Gradle User Home"

I realized the Intellij is looking at another `gradle.properties` file:

```
C:\Users\<user-X>\.gradle <-- I was focusing on this folder
C:\Users\<user-Y>\.gradle <-- while Intellij was looking at that folder
```